# Not able to connect to private Ethereum Network with metamask

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, metamask

I am running a private Ethereum Network in a cloud VM. I started the node with these arguments:

> geth --datadir test --networkid 123 --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcport 30308 
>       --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpcapi 
>       "admin,debug,miner,personal,ssh,txpool,db,eth,net,web3" console

I've opened the port 30308 in the firewall too.
I am able to interact with the node through another vm, also with postman.
But I am not able to connect to the network with the metamask plugin that I've installed in my browser.
What could probably be the issue? I just get this error in every retries

> Oops! Something went wrong.

The address I provide in my metamask is like:

> http://my_cloud_ip:30308